# pandas filtering: selecting multiple column if either statement is true

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have `p_order_items` data frame that looks like below:

```
JOBNO   JOBNO2  JOBNO4  JOBNO5  JOBNO6  
50626   S14868  NaN      NaN    NaN 
28196   S12839  NaN      22222  NaN 
23907   S12392  NaN      NaN    222222  
38833   S14050  S14051   NaN    NaN
```

I'm trying to pull out rows where there is a number in either of the columns `JOBNO2`, `JOBNO4`, `JOBNO5`, `JOBNO6`?

I can see how to do it when all are true using "&" but not if either is true "or":

```
p_order_items[p_order_items.JOBNO2.notnull() &                                                 
              p_order_items.JOBNO4.notnull() &                                                 
              p_order_items.JOBNO5.notnull() &                                                 
              p_order_items.JOBNO6.notnull()]
```

Can anyone tell me how to get all the rows that have a number/value in any of the columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace "&" with "|":

```py
p_order_items[p_order_items.JOBNO2.notnull() | p_order_items.JOBNO4.notnull() | p_order_items.JOBNO5.notnull() | p_order_items.JOBNO6.notnull()]
```

Comment: what does the pipe charactor do in pandas?

Comment: analogical to "&" ~ and, "|" ~ or

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
p_order_items[(p_order_items.JOBNO2.notnull()) | (p_order_items.JOBNO4.notnull()) | (p_order_items.JOBNO5.notnull()) | (p_order_items.JOBNO6.notnull())]
```

In `pandas`, "&" stands for `and`, pipe ("|") stands for `or`.